# get_object_vars() for non-OOP class

Tags: php

In OOP where there's classes and objects, I can use `get_object_vars()` to get a list of all properties/vars in that class.

In this case, I'm not using OOP. I have some functions and some vars declared outside the functions. When I need to access some of these vars inside a function, I re-declare it as `global` inside the function. But how do I get a list of all vars declared outside. Is this possible? I'm looking for something like `get_object_vars` but for non-OOP code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) to get all the variables within the scope that `get_defined_vars()` is called.

Comment: +1 For correct answer. As a note though, this will also return PHP global variables like `$_POST` and `$GLOBALS`